# Where is the utorrent default download directory?

Tags: downloads, utorrent

I'm using Ubuntu and I've downloaded a file using utorrent, but I don't know where the utorrent default download directory is! Where is it and how can I change it?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like utorrent is running with wine. 
If you are using mapped drive in wine, you may find it under `~/.wine/drive_c/users`..

Use the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to hide/unhide hidden files (such as `.wine`)

If you haven't changed utorrent download preferences after install, files will be in different download folder, which is of path `~/snap/utorrent/common/.wine/drive_c/users/<user>/downloads`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I found it in

```
~/snap/utorrent/common/.wine/drive_c/users/
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the help center on the utorrent site](http://help.utorrent.com/customer/portal/articles/257686), you can find

> Navigate to **Options > Preferences** and click on **Directories** from the list on the left.
>
> You will see an option to change various options such as the directory of your downloads, completed downloads, .torrent files and more.

Comment: I was changed it couple of time and I was saved it but every time I go to options > preferences > directories I see nothing was changed

Answer (score 1):

The downloaded torrents are saved in the folder where you have installed uTorrent Server.

In my case it was /opt folder.
Navigate to the folder and you will find all your downloaded torrents.

Comment: Experience has taught me to take the claims in answers seriously no matter how improbable they seem, but why would an application like uTorrent save huge downloads to the root filesystem instead of to the home directory? This will eat all the available disk space on the SSD for users who have root installed on an SSD and home installed on an HDD in order to save valuable disk space on the SSD.

Answer (score 1):

(Ubuntu 18.04/uTorrent Server) If you haven't specified a directory in the settings, it should download to your home folder: `/home/[username]/[my-file-here]`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no default download location for utorrent. If you have not given any download location in utorrent, it just discards your downloads. It keeps in some secret location from where literally you can never get the file.

If you want to set the location then click on the settings and then there is an option "Directories". Under which a field is " Move completed downloads to:". Set the path there for your download location. Fyi I am on Ubuntu 18.x and utorrents 13.x. The utorrents is running as a server and can access it on a browser.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
/home/***ognjen***/.local/share/Trash/files/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/

where ognjen is my acc username

Answer (score 0):

I found my directory in

> /snap/utorrent/common/.wine/drive_c/users/ubuntured/Downloads/

I would suggest a search for drive_c or .wine folder to get the exact location of your download